# Meaning of ポンポンしている

Tags: meaning, onomatopoeia

What's the meaning of ポンポンしている in the following sentence? Context: a girl is touching his friend's boxing gloves and then says:

> へーなんかポンポンしててカワイー

Of all the meanings I found on dictionaries (cheerleaders' pom-poms as a noun, bang-bang, one after another, outspokenly as adverbs/onomatopoeia) none seems to fit the context. Could it mean that they are soft like cheerleaders' pom-poms, and therefore cute (even though I don't think boxing gloves are that soft)?
 Thank you for your help!

Comment: I think it's just a sort of "onomatopoeia" saying they're puffy and padded.

Comment: Or popping-hopping cute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this context, 「ぽんぽん/ポンポン」 would mean "***plump***".  It has absolutely nothing to do with "pom-poms".

「ポンポンしている」＝「ふくれている」 or 「ふっくらしている」

「ぱんぱん」 would be a synonym.

To comment on your question title, we do not really say 「ポンポンする」; We say「ポンポンしている」.

Answer (score 0):

ポンポン is pong-pong or pompon.

It's one of [onomatopoeia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onomatopoeia) and mimetic words like ping-pong or ding-dong or tick-tack.

Sounds like bouncy like [this](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=bouncy&newwindow=1&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj76LCj_JXTAhXIvbwKHfeSD1oQ_AUICCgB&biw=1366&bih=610).